# Join two queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I join those two queries into one with already join in them?

```
SELECT *
FROM   post 
       LEFT JOIN post_plus 
              ON ( post.id = post_plus.news_id ) 
       where approve = 1 
ORDER  BY fixed DESC, 
          date DESC 
LIMIT  0, 7; 

SELECT c1.postid
FROM   post_category c1
       JOIN post_category c2
         ON c1.postid = c2.postid
WHERE  c1.categoryid IN ( 130, 3, 4, 5 )
       AND c2.categoryid = 73
```

Comment: This might be appropraite for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If post has a foreign key to link post_category:

```
SELECT *
FROM post p
JOIN post_category pc
ON p.fk_post_category = pc.id
JOIN post_category pc2
ON pc.postid = pc2.postid
LEFT JOIN post_plus pp
          ON ( p.id = pp.news_id ) 
where approve = 1 
and pc.categoryid IN ( 130, 3, 4, 5 )
   AND pc2.categoryid = 73  
ORDER  BY fixed DESC, 
      date DESC 
LIMIT  0, 7;
```

Obviously your result is limited as the first query. If doesn't exist a relation between post and post category, please post how you want to put these tables

Answer (score -1):

You can simply join these query using **union**, if both query results similar columns with similar datatype.

```
(SELECT *
FROM   post 
       LEFT JOIN post_plus 
              ON ( post.id = post_plus.news_id ) 
       where approve = 1 
ORDER  BY fixed DESC, 
          date DESC 
LIMIT  0, 7 )

UNION

(SELECT c1.postid
FROM   post_category c1
       JOIN post_category c2
         ON c1.postid = c2.postid
WHERE  c1.categoryid IN ( 130, 3, 4, 5 )
       AND c2.categoryid = 73);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: The two queries can't have the same number of columns. They're at least four columns in the top query. A union will not work.